# Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to pass this warning?

[image: Screen]

### Code

```
const Main = (header, navigation) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {navigation !== false && <Navigation />}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

i tried this but still have the same warning

```
<Main navigation>
....
</Main>
```

Console output `true`

```
<Main navigation={true}>
....
</Main>
```

Console output `true`

```
<Main navigation={+true}>
....
</Main>
```

Console output `1`

```
<Main>
....
</Main>
```

Console output `undefined`

Comment: it should be `return`, not `retun`.

Comment: @OuterSoda sorry that's a typo in here, not from my code

Comment: Where is your boolean attribute `exact` in the code above?

Comment: attribute `exac` in  `<Route exact element={ <Main/> }  path="/" />` but the warning came from Main component, when i tried to delete {navigation !== .....} the warning dissapear

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
const Main = (header, navigation) => {
  if (navigation !== false) return <Navigation />
  return <></>
}
```

Comment: how the {navigation...} inside the <> and <div>?

Comment: no you don't need to transmit anything just leave it like that: `<Main navigation>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Main = (header, navigation) => {
  return (
    !!navigation ? <Navigation />:<></>
  )
}
```

Comment: What about `!!navigation ? <Navigation /> : <></>`?

Comment: Reference: [MDN: References > Logical NOT (!) > Double NOT (!!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!)